# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y = \sqrt{x}$ at the point $(9,3)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y = \sqrt{x}$ at the point $(9,3)$.

I did

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{9+h}-3}{h} \frac{\sqrt(9+h)+3}{\sqrt(9+h)+3} = \frac{9+h-3}{h\sqrt{9+h}+3}= \frac{6}{\sqrt{9+h}+3}= \frac{6}{6}=1.$$

Comment: Nilou please describe what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. Have you gone over in your class what a tangent line is? How you find it? etc.

Comment: I did f(x+h)-f(x)/h then =sqrt(9+h)-3/h * sqrt(9+h)+3/sqrt(9+h)+3= 9+h-3/h(sqrt(9+h)+3= 6/sqrt(9+h)+3= 6/6 =1. but that's not the correct answer

Comment: Instead of finding the derivative using limits (which also would work if done correctly), do you know how to derive $x^\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: do you know how to derive $x^2$?

Answer (score 1):

let $f(x) = x^a$

$f'(x) = a*x^{a-1}$

for example:
$f(x) = x^2$ -> $f'(x) = 2*x^1$

$f(x) = x^3$ -> $f'(x) = 3*x^2$

So...

if $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{2}$ what is $f'(x)$?

Comment: f'(x) = 1/2*x^-1/2?

Comment: correct. $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}$ and what is $x^\frac{-1}{2}$? How do you make the minus disappear? remember: $x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$

Comment: you just have to do 1/ x^1/2

Comment: correct. so u got: $f'(x) = \frac{1]{2}*\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ what is $x^\frac{1}{2}$? is it not the square root of x?

Comment: yes I see that it is.

Comment: so... overall, u got $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$? Do we agree on this? :)

Comment: OH I see. So it should equal to 1/6 not 6. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. But more importantly, remember that $f'(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. More important than solving 1 question right, is knowing and understanding the formula for the derivative. and generally speaking, if we dont have $\sqrt{x}$ but some function of square root of x: $f'(\sqrt{g(x)}) = \frac{g'(x)}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}$

Comment: Yeah it totally makes sense now. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Oria Gruber's answer:

If

$y = \sqrt x, \tag{1}$

then

$x = y^2, \tag{2}$

so

$dx/dy = 2y = 2\sqrt x, \tag{3}$

whence

$dy/dx = (dx/dy)^{-1} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt x}; \tag{4}$

thus when $x = 9$ we obtain

$dy/dx = 1/6, \tag{5}$

so the equation for the desired tangent line is

$y - 3 = \frac{1}{6}(x - 9). \tag{6}$

The derivative $dx/dy$ of $x$ with repect to $y$ may be easily had using the definition

$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}((f(x + h) -f(x) / h), \tag{7}$

with which the OP seems familiar.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @ nilou:  glad to help out!  Best, RKL.